# Unremovable breakpoint

Tags: macos, swift, vector, breakpoints

i'm new to Swift and tried to code a litte command line tool for vector calculation. When I run it, the program gets interrupted and shows me a green line. I tried, but can't get rid of it. Do you have any ideas?
mormod

```
func isLineParallelTo(l: Line) -> Bool{
    if(self.directionVector.isLinearlyDependentTo(v: l.directionVector)){
        let pointToTest = Point(name: "p", x: l.positionVector.x, y: l.positionVector.y, z: l.positionVector.z)
        //println("\(pointToTest.displayPoint())")
        println("\(self.isPointOnLine(pointToTest))") //says false
        let b:Bool = self.isPointOnLine(pointToTest)
        if(b){ //Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1
            return false
        }
        else{
            return true
        }
    }
    else{
        return false
    }
}
```

whole code (Line)

```
import Foundation

class Line {
let name: String
let positionVector: Vector
let directionVector: Vector

func isPointOnLine(p: Point) -> Bool{
    let pv = Vector(name: "pv", x: p.x, y: p.y, z: p.z)
    let pvMinusPosition = Vector(name: "pvMinusPosition", x: pv.x-self.positionVector.x, y: pv.y-self.positionVector.y, z: pv.z-self.positionVector.z)
    if(pvMinusPosition.isLinearlyDependentTo(v: directionVector)){
        return true
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

//TODO: are lines parallel?
func isLineParallelTo(l: Line) -> Bool{
    if(self.directionVector.isLinearlyDependentTo(v: l.directionVector)){
        let pointToTest = Point(name: "p", x: l.positionVector.x, y: l.positionVector.y, z: l.positionVector.z)
        println("\(pointToTest.displayPoint())")
        println("\(self.isPointOnLine(pointToTest))")
        let b:Bool = self.isPointOnLine(pointToTest)
        if(b){
            return false
        }
        else{
            return true
        }
    }
    else{
        return false
    }
}
//TODO: are lines equal?
//TODO: are lines 'windschief'?

init(name: String, position positionVector: Vector, direction       directionVector: Vector){
    self.name = name;
    self.positionVector = positionVector;
    self.directionVector = directionVector;
}
}
```

Comment: You may have set a breakpoint accidentally. Check that there isn't a blue tick at the left of the highlighted line, on the line number. If there is one, grab it and throw it away from the gutter.

Comment: @EricD. oh god thank you! I didn't see that at all

Comment: It could be a crash too, add a printscreen next time it happen so we can see what is happening and help you better

Comment: if(pvMinusPosition.isLinearlyDependentTo(v: directionVector)){ return true }
else{ return false } change it to ==>   return  pvMinusPosition.isLinearlyDependentTo(v: directionVector)

Comment: let b:Bool = self.isPointOnLine(pointToTest);  if(b){ return false  }
else{ return true } change it to ==> return !isPointOnLine(pointToTest)